# "External Identity User" Profile not available

Tags: profile, identity

I am trying to complete this trailhead challenge - [setting up external identity](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/identity_external/identity_external_prepare) .  I am not able to find the "External Identity User" profile in any of my orgs, even thought they use custom domains and identity for Internal Users. Is there something that needs to be done in order to enable this profile/User License?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External Identity User licenses are available at an extra cost. Contact your AE for pricing.

Five External Identity User licenses are included in standard DEs.

Comment: I'm using a Standard DE but don't see any External Identity User licenses, nor does it show on the profile list

Comment: External Identity Licenses should be available in any org provisioned in the last two releases. In prod orgs, you can purchase them. In a DE, you are subject to the whims of when your org was created.

Answer (score 6):

You have to sign up for a new developer org(https://developer.salesforce.com). After this goto setup and search profiles. You can see this [image: All profiles]

Comment: Is it not available in older orgs? What if I was actually trying to set up external identity in a production org and not just do a trailhead challenge? It's a little bit worthless to know how to do something if I can't replicate it in my production org